# How to discard a checkout for a driveItem using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to cancel a checkout using graph api.
But I could not find any relevant API. @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem 
Is there a way to do that using REST API?